# How to get rid of hours, minutes, and seconds when displaying a date filtered with localize (Django templates)?

Tags: python, django, date, django-templates

How do I get rid of hours, minutes and seconds when I display a localized date (`{{ post.pub_date|localize }}`) in a Django template?

If I only use a normal date (something like `post.pub_date|date:"d m Y"`), I can display only the day, month, and year (and not the hours, minutes, and s). With the localize filter, I can't seem to control what I display.

As a last resort, I have transformed the datetime objects to date objects in my views before sending the posts, but it's more work (I for loop in the list of posts).

Thanks.

Comment: Filters are chainable. What does {{ post.pub_date|localize|date:"d m Y" }} produce for you?

Comment: I tried that, but it forces the format of the date (day first, month second, year third). In some countries, the month comes first, and the day after, or the month may or may not be capitalized...

Comment: I hoped there would be something like `{{ post.pub_date|localize(%D, %M, %Y) }}`, where %D just tells there needs to be a day somewhere without forcing its position in the string.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but of course, you can always write your own template filter. It's actually pretty easy.

Comment: I'll definitely try that and update this post. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome. Please post your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Django has built-in support for localized dateformatting; it's just disabled by default. Check out [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#format-localization) for more information, but the short answer is that you just set `USE_L10N=True` in your settings.py.

Comment: I am actually already loading l10n. The thing is, the date is localized (for the french locale, it displays: '1 mars 2013 10:00:22', as it should, instead of 'march 01, 2013 10:00:22'). The issue I have is to get rid of the '10:00:22' part in the template (and not the view) without forcing any format.

Comment: I believe you'll have to define custom formats for each locale. Check out "Creating custom format files" on the page I linked.